# converting con-convex region to convex

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry, integer-programming, non-convex-optimization

I'm trying to model a problem using Linear Programming theory, though the feasible region of the problem is non-convex. Yet, I think using Big-M and some binary variables this region can be converted to a convex feasible region.
Is there any way to convert the following non-convex region to a convex region (with higher dimension) using integer programming "if-then" constraints?[image]

Comment: Um, what?  You are asking for a hint on how to turn a nonconvex region into a convex region by extending the dimension?  I think the community at large could use a hint like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a binary variable $z$, where $z=1$ indicates that the point $(x,y)$ is in the $1 \times 3$ rectangle and $z=0$ indicates that $(x,y)$ is in the trapezoid.  Now impose the following linear big-M constraints to enforce that:
\begin{align}
0 \le x &\le 2 + z \\
x - y &\le 3z \\
1-z \le y &\le 2-z \\
\end{align}
Checking the two cases, we see that
\begin{align}
z=1 &\implies (x,y) \in [0,3] \times [0,1] \\
z=0 &\implies x \in [0,y] \land y \in [1,2] \\
\end{align}
More generally, you can represent a union of polyhedra $P_i$ by introducing a binary variable $z_i$ for each one, along with linear constraints $\sum_i z_i=1$ and linear big-M constraints that enforce $z_i=1 \implies x \in P_i$.